# What are some use cases for HTMLENCODE?

Tags: visualforce, xss

Can someone give me some use cases when I'd use HTMLENCODE? Or help explain the example in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_scontrols.htm) a little better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you've linked to is pretty clear. Any time you are trying to output data that could include untrusted html, you should use `HTMLENCODE`.

> **HTMLENCODE**
>   Encodes text and merge field values for use in HTML by replacing characters that are reserved in HTML, such as the greater-than sign (`>`), with HTML entity equivalents, such as `&gt;`.
>
> ...
>
> To use `HTMLENCODE` to secure the previous example, change the `<apex:outputText>` to the following:
>
> ```
> <apex:outputText value=" {!HTMLENCODE(myTextField)}" escape="false"/>
> ```
>
> If a user enters `<script>alert('xss')` and clicks Update It, the JavaScript is not be executed. Instead, the string is encoded and the page displays Value of myTextField is `<script>alert('xss')`.

Take a look also at [Secure Coding Cross Site Scripting](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting#HTMLENCODE), which goes into more depth. It would be difficult to quote what is relevant there. Too much of its content is relevant, and the entire document is worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

For example, suppose you have a string that contains HTML code including code that mentioned in this link http://f2.org/links/webauth/entities.html#html3

SO, in this case, you may want to render that html code in Visualforce page without any rendering issue

In this case, you can use

```
<apex:outputText value=" {!HTMLENCODE(myTextField)}" escape="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to pass values through a URL like a button, When creating a new record. You can type field_name__c = {!merge_field__c} and everything is all good if it's one word.

Say you want to pass the Account Name into a field on the new record. If that Account Name is "Dan Dan Account" the URL will break because of the space. What if the Account Name is "Dan & Dan Account" the URL will break because of the &. In order to avoid these unpleasantries you must use URLENCODE or HTMLENCODE on the field so that the spaces and characters that are used in urls are encoded with HTML allowable characters.

I guarantee you'll make the button it'll work in testing and UAT and even in production for a few days or weeks. And then one day you'll get an email the button doesn't work. You'll spend hours debugging the issue to come find out someone wrote "A & S Co." and you forgot to encode the field. It happened to me and it'll happen to you.